# Default values for a method

Tags: dictionary, methods, groovy, default-value

I'm trying to specify default values to a `Map`. Is this how it's done?

```
static def AddOrder( String key, Map order = [
                                                id: '',
                                                campaign_id: '',
                                                email_id: '',
                                                email: '',
                                                total: 0.0d,
                                                order_date: '',
                                                shipping: 0.0d,
                                                tax: 0.0d,
                                                store_id: '',
                                                store_name: '',
                                                items:  [
                                                            line_num: 0,
                                                            product_id: 0,
                                                            sku: '',
                                                            product_name: '',
                                                            category_id: 0,
                                                            qty: 0.0d,
                                                            cost: 0.0d
                                                        ]
                                            ] ){
    contactMC( key, action, order)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply test it? A very short program will show you that indeed, that's how default map parameters work:

```
def testMethod(Map map = [ foo: 'bar' ]) {
    return map.foo
}

println testMethod() //outputs bar
println testMethod([foo:'baz']) //outputs baz
```

Comment: It seems kind of bulky. I was looking for another way.

Comment: You can always define the default map somewhere else, use a default empty map (`static def AddOrder( String key, Map order = [:])`) and make the first line of your method `order = order ?: defaultOrder` (where `defaultOrder` is your default map that you've defined somewhere). It's also reusable this way, should you need that.